# Horizontal ProgressDialog not shown in android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have the MainActivity as this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bo = new Operation(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void op_perform(View v) throws Exception { //call this when a button is pressed
        try {
            bo.demo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

The Operation class has the following lines of code:

```
Context con;

Operation(Context ac) {
        con = ac;
        barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
        updateBarHandler = new Handler();

    }


    public void demo() {
        barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
        barProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Image ...");
        barProgressDialog.setMessage("Download in progress ...");
        barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(barProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        barProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
        barProgressDialog.setMax(20);
        barProgressDialog.show();
            ...
```

But, i'm not getting the progress dialog at all in my screen. I want the progress dialog to be a determinate horizontal one. This is just a piece of code and i need to put these in the Asyn task. But the processdialog is not even showing. Recommended solutions. I'm a beginner to android.

Comment: change `bo = new Operation(getApplicationContext())` to `bo = new Operation(MainActivity.this)`

Comment: Call demo like this MainActivity.this.bo.demo();

Comment: `MainActivity.this` Worked. But i'm not sure why getApplicationContext() can't solve the problem. Is there any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of what you need: [http://turboprogramacion.blogspot.cl](http://turboprogramacion.blogspot.cl/2016/02/android-dialogs-como-crear-un.html)

```
private ProgressDialog barraProgreso;
private Handler handler;

private void mostrarBarraProgreso(){
    barraProgreso = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    barraProgreso.setTitle("Buscando...");
    barraProgreso.setMessage("Progreso...");
    barraProgreso.setProgressStyle(barraProgreso.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    barraProgreso.setProgress(0);
    barraProgreso.setMax(10);
    barraProgreso.show();

    handler = new Handler();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (barraProgreso.getProgress() <= barraProgreso.getMax()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            barraProgreso.incrementProgressBy(1);
                        }
                    });

                    if(barraProgreso.getProgress() == barraProgreso.getMax()){
                        barraProgreso.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }catch (InterruptedException er){
                er.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```